# Write a python program to create a list and converting the data type of the first element into integer

Tags: python

```
list=["ABART 20","CDXEF 50","BKWRK 25"]
g=int(list[0])
g
```

Output: " invalid literal for int() with base 10:'ABART 20'.

Can anyone explain me ??

Comment: Do you expect that to output `20`?

Comment: Well that looks very logical, since how would you convert `'ABART 20'` to an `int`?

Comment: What other result would you expect from attempting to convert a non-numeric string to integer?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python tutorial string integer", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast the string `"ABART 20"` as an integer, which obviously fails.

You can get the numbers in your string like this:

```
mylist=["ABART 20","CDXEF 50","BKWRK 25"] # don't name your list "list"

nums = [int(a.split()[1]) for a in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[20, 50, 25]
```